# Facets and scale_color_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

With the command `scale_color_manual`, you can manually change the color of your plot.

```
dataPlot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=z))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#636363", "#de2d26", "#636363", "#636363"))
```

Is there a way to manually change the colors used for each facet? So, for example, if I have facets with the variable `variable`, how can I set up `scale_color_manual` so that I can set the colors for each group `x` of each facet?

```
dataPlot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=z))+
  facet_grid(~variable)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#636363", "#de2d26", "#636363", "#636363"))
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please `dput(df)` and paste in your question to help you !

Comment: You could pass a named vector in 'value' i.e. the key can be unique values of 'variable'

Answer (score 2):

If you want a different single-color for each facet, this is effectively duplicating between faceting and coloring: use the same variable(s) for `color=` that you facet on.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(gear), color = factor(cyl))) +
  facet_grid(~ cyl) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green4", "blue"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with redundant facets/colors]

If you're asking for different color *scales* for each facet, that's a different story, and I believe not possible with basic `ggplot2`. There are three relevant extensions for that, currently untested but they all allege to support this. In no particular order:

- `ggnewscale` ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggnewscale/), [GH](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale))
- `ggh4x` ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggh4x) [GH](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x))
- `relayer`([GH](https://github.com/clauswilke/relayer))

Comment: Yes -- what I am looking for is setting different color scales for each facet. It looks like the package `ggh4x` may be of use here, though I can't seem to install it. Any other alternative?

Comment: Nope. I have plans to clone/fork and possibly contribute to `ggh4x`, but I haven't started yet. If you're having errors with installation, depending on the error it might be good to give the installation-failure as feedback as an [issue](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues) (unless [ggh4x#24](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/24) is related).